# Position fixed on scroll starts before it reaches the top (top div)

Tags: javascript, css, position, fixed

I have now so that `#filter` (my sidebar white select list) becomes `fixed` 
when it reaches the top and stay there during the scrolling until it reaches the foot and releases.

My problem is that I have a `<div>` box in the head that is positioned `fixed`,
so `#filter` will not be fixed from the get to the top of the page.
which means that I get a snatch before it attaches to position fixed. 
How can I get it to become `fixed` 40px before reaching the top?

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/realitylab/6r3WZ/26/)**

```
$(function() {
    var top = $('#filter').offset().top,
        footTop = $('#outside_footer_wrapper').offset().top,
        maxY = footTop - $('#filter').outerHeight();
        console.log(top , footTop, maxY);

    $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(y);
        if (y > top) {
            console.log('mayor');
            $('#filter').addClass('fixed').removeAttr('style');
            if (y > maxY-130){
                var min = y - maxY + 130;
                console.log('mayor y menor', min);
                $('#filter').css('top','-'+min+'px');
            }
        } else {
            $('#filter').removeClass('fixed');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/change the if statement to this:

```
console.log(y);
if (y >= (top-y)) {
```

Here's the link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r3WZ/27/)

**UPDATE**

Change it back to this `$('#filter').css('top','-'+min+'px');`

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r3WZ/30/)

Comment: Can you put a starting value (20px from top)?

Comment: then just add 20 to top variable... so anywhere before $(window).scroll

Comment: When I use the change you wrote so it settles over the foot which I do not want it to do.

Comment: exactly how do I print the variable that contains the value of 20px?

Comment: i've fixed the footer problem, forgot to change the var back to min instead of yme. ill put it on my post. also, i ddnt get your last question

Comment: How can I add a variable with a value in?

Comment: Now I hack on both top and foot.

Comment: i don't get where you want to add that variable and for what purposes. first, if you add a height anywhere in the header, js will pick it up dynamically as it'll get counted on your var top = $('#filter').offset().top... but if you want to just add a variable with a value (let's say 20px), then just do top += 20; before the code $(window).scroll(.... hope this answers your question